# Stripe AJAX PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, angularjs

The below is my code I'm using for my Stripe Subscription Payments, because the site I'm implementing this into is AngularJS I want to keep the site from Refreshing so I'm opting for this AJAX option.

I have commented out a piece of the PHP which is

```
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    'customer' => $customer->id,
    'amount' => $amount,
    'currency' => 'gbp'
));
```

If I exclude this, the payment goes through once and I'm unsure how this application is able to process the `charge` if there is no call for it in the PHP file.

If I include the above snippet then the charge goes through twice.

My **config.php** only has `require_once('Stripe.php');` along with my API keys.

So I'm hoping someone could explain why the charge goes through without the charge code piece in there if my code is actually okay for me to continue with.

**HTML**

```
<button id="proBtn">Subscribe</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('HIDDEN');

    $('#proBtn').click(function(){
        var token = function(res){
            var $input = $('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(res.id);
            var tokenId = $input.val();
            var email = res.email;

            setTimeout(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/assets/lib/charge.php',
                    cache: false,
                    data:{ stripeEmail : email, stripeToken:tokenId, stripePlan: 'pro' },
                    type:'POST'
                })
                .done(function(data){
                    // If Payment Success
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#proBtn').html('Thank You').addClass('disabled');
                })
                .error(function(){
                    $('#proBtn').html('Error, Unable to Process Payment').addClass('disabled');
                });
            },500);
            //$('form:first-child').append($input).submit();
        };

        StripeCheckout.open({
            key:         'HIDDEN', // Your Key
            address:     false,
            amount:      500,
            currency:    'gbp',
            name:        'Pro Account',
            description: '',
            panelLabel:  'Checkout',
            allowRememberMe: false,
            token:       token
        });
        return false;
    });
```

**charge.php**

```
<?php
  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/lib/config.php');

  $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
  $email  = $_POST['stripeEmail'];

  $plan  = $_POST['stripePlan'];

  if ( $plan == 'pro' ) {
      $amount = 500;
      $amountFormat = number_format( $amount / 100, 2) ;
      $plan = 'pro';
  } 

  if ( $plan == 'team' ) {
      $amount = 2000;
      $amountFormat = number_format( $amount / 100, 2) ;
      $plan = 'team';
  } 

  Stripe_Plan::retrieve("pro");
  Stripe_Plan::retrieve("team");

  $customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
      'email' => $email,
      'card'  => $token,
      'plan' => $plan
  ));

try {
    /*
    $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
        'customer' => $customer->id,
        'amount' => $amount,
        'currency' => 'gbp'
    ));*/
    echo 'success';
} catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
    echo "The card has been declined";
    echo $token;
}

  print_r($token);
  echo '<br/>';
  print_r($email);
  echo '<br/>';
  echo $customer->id;

  echo '<h1>Successfully charged '.$amountFormat.'!</h1>';
?>
```

Comment: Why do you need the setTimeout in there on the button click?

Comment: You REALLY need to add some data validation/sanitation before trying to execute a charge operation.  You cannot trust that the input data in `$_POST` is sanitized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a customer in Stripe it automatically charges them if you pass in a plan. You're basically saying create this customer and sign them up for this plan. That's why you are charging them twice.

Here's a link to the Customer API:

https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer